# Property doesn't exist on component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this Angular 4 component :

```
export class MenuComponent {

constructor(private menuService: MenuService) { }


@Input(nodes):any;

   getMenu(path:string): void {
   this.menuService.getData(path).subscribe(data => {
         // Read the result field from the JSON response.

         let newValue = JSON.stringify(data).replace('{"Node":', '[');
         newValue = newValue.substring(0,newValue.length - 1);
         newValue+="]";
        const menu=JSON.parse(newValue);
         this.nodes = menu;
      });

 }
}
```

I keep getting this error: `Property 'nodes' does not exist on type 'MenuComponent'` and I have no idea why because the `nodes` property is right there.

Comment: `@Input() nodes: any;`?

Comment: what's wrong with it?

Comment: Well compare my comment with what you've actually written!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally define @input variables in this way.

```
  @Input() nodes: any;
```

I can see two problems

1. from the view you your component getting `undefined` or not getting value. so make sure parent component is sending proper value `[nodes]="'this is a value"'`
2. in angular component life cycle, make sure the value of `nodes` is coming on time.

You can also add `ngInit` life cycle hook and set a default value in case did not receive any thing

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.nodes = this.nodes || '';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can provide Input in two ways,

```
 @Input() hero: Hero;
 @Input('master') masterName: string;
```

In your code you are providing public property name (`bindingPropertyName`) but there is no property which can be used in component class,

```
 @Input(nodes):any;
```

Read more about `@Input` [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding).